# Processing compile error caused by RxTx lib

Tags: java, osx-lion, arduino, processing, rxtx

I use processing to read from Arduino Serial. To do this i use the processing class Serial, but when i compile, i get this error:

```
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Invalid memory access of location 0xb1bbcb70 eip=0x137ea90c
```

And it opens a window with this message sketch_dec11a has unexpectedly quit when using the plugin librxtxSerial.jnilib
My code is this :

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial mySerial = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[1]);
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Did you read this: http://forum.processing.org/topic/rxtx-version-mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried out this? http://wiki.processing.org/w/Serial_Issues
Check what versions are in your Processing library folder.